# Reset Password function not working

Tags: javascript, php, sql, codeigniter

I create a password reset function, where it works when user enter his id then the id will be inserted into the query to find the password of the user. when the password has been found, then the password will be sent to the user email.
email obtained from user id. But my function is not work, and I don't get any error message, so I don't know  what's wrong with my code.

--This is my view--

```
    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="statusMsg"></p>
        <form role="form" id="formPass" action='<?php echo base_url() ?>kirim_form' method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="masukkanNpk">Masukkan NPK:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="npk" placeholder="Masukkan NPK Anda"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn" onclick="kirimContactForm()">KIRIM</button>
    </div>
```

--this is my function after user submit ID--

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    /*
    Forgotpassword email sender:
    No view
    */
class Kirim_form extends Xcentrix_Controller 
{
         public function ForgotPass()
       {
             $email = $this->input->post('npk');

             $findemail = $this->db->query("select email from cc_customer where npk = '".$email."'");
             if($findemail){
              $this->usermodel->sendpassword($findemail);        
               }else{
              // $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',' Email not found!');
              echo "Email not found!";
              redirect(base_url().'/','refresh');
          }
       }

    //funtion to get email of user to send password
     public function ForgotPassword($email)
     {
            $this->db->select('email');
            $this->db->from('cc_customer'); 
            $this->db->where('npk', $email); 
            $query=$this->db->get();
            return $query->row_array();
     }
     public function sendpassword($findemail)
    {
            $email = $findemail['email'];
            $query1=$this->db->query("SELECT * from cc_customer a,cc_user b  where a.npk = b.npk and a.email = '".$email."' ");
            $row=$query1->result_array();
            if ($query1->num_rows()>0)

    {
            $yourPass = md5($row->password);
            $this->db->where('email', $email);
            $mail_message='Dear '.$row[0]['customer_name'].','. "\r\n";
            $mail_message.='<br>Lupa Password ITCare Berhasil!';
            $mail_message.='Password ITCare atas NPK '.$row->npk.'('.$row->customer_name.') adalah <b>'.$yourPass.'</b>'."\r\n";
            $mail_message.='<br>Terima Kasih';
            $mail_message.='<br>ITCare System';        
            date_default_timezone_set('UTC+7');
            require FCPATH.'assets/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
            $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
            $mail->Host = "172.16.5.20";
            $mail->Port = 25;
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;   
            $mail->Username = "helpdesk@acc.co.id";    
            $mail->setFrom('helpdesk@acc.co.id', 'Rizki');
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->addAddress('dpalevi@gmail.com');
            // $mail->addAddress($email);
            $mail->Subject = '[ITCARE] Konfirmasi Password';
            $mail->Body    = $mail_message;
            $mail->AltBody = $mail_message;
    if (!$mail->send()) {
         // $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Failed to send password, please try again!');
        echo "Failed to send password, please try again!";
    } else {
       // $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Password sent to your email!');
       echo "Password sent to your email!";
       $status = 'ok';
    }
      redirect(base_url().'/','refresh');        
    }
    else
    {  
     // $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Email not found try again!');
     echo "Email not found try again!";
     redirect(base_url().'/','refresh');
    }
    }


   }
 ?>
```

-- and it's some javascript --

```
function kirimContactForm(){
    var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    var npk = $('#npk').val();
    // var email = $().val();
    if(npk.trim() == '' ){
  alert('Masukkan NPK Anda.');
        $('#npk').focus();
  return false;
 }else{
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:$('#formPass').attr('action'),
            data:'contactFrmSubmit=1&npk='+npk,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
            },
            success:function(msg){
                if(msg == 'ok'){
                    $('#masukkanNpk').val('');
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Password akan dikirimkan ke email:' , '<br><br> Jika tidak menerima email harap menghubungi helpdesk di <u>021-75998699</u></p>');
                }
                else{
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Mohon Maaf email anda tidak ada di sistem ITCare. Password akan dikirim ke atasan anda di:', '<br><br>Jika tidak menerima email harap menghubungi helpdesk di <u>021-75998699</u> </span>');
                }
                $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks advance

Comment: try after change form action to  `action='<?php echo base_url() ?>kirim_form/ForgotPass'`

Comment: I already try it but still not working @B. Desai